# Подсветка ключевых слов в TextBlock или RichTextBox

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения, wpf

Юзер выбирает текстовый файл, содержимое считывается в `TextBlock`/`RichTextBox`. После этого юзер нажимает на кнопку "Форматировать" и в `TextBlock`/`RichTextBox` должен добавиться этот текст, но найденные слова должны поменять свой цвет или шрифт. Как это реализовать?

Код XAML

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="75"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Name="TextBlock1" Grid.Row="0" Background="Yellow"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Name="ButtonOpenFile" Content="OpenFile" Height="30" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="OpenFile_Click"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Name="ButtonFormat" Content="Format" Height="30" Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="ButtonFormat_Click"/>
</Grid>
```

Код C#

```
    private void OpenFile()
    {
        OpenFileDialog dlg = new OpenFileDialog();            
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
        dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt";            
        Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();

        if (result == true)
        {                     
            StreamReader r = new StreamReader(dlg.FileName, System.Text.Encoding.Default, false);
            TextBlock1.Text = r.ReadToEnd();
            this.Title = dlg.FileName;
        }
    }

    private void ButtonFormat_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string str = TextBlock1.Text;
        TextBlock1.Text = "";
        string pattern = @"(\W|^)hello(\W|$)";
        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
        Match match = regex.Match(str);

        //System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush color = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Red;
        //System.Windows.Media.SolidColorBrush color2 = System.Windows.Media.Brushes.Black;

        // отображаем все совпадения
        while (match.Success)
        {
            // Здесь добавляются в Текст найденные слова "hello"
            // реализовать изменение цвета или размер шрифта найденных слов
            // другие слова должны оставаться такими, как были.
            TextBlock1.Text += match.Groups[0].Value + " ";             
            match = match.NextMatch();
        }

    }
```

Comment: при чем здесь регулярные выражения ? Вам же просто нужен способ подсветки участка текста в RichTextBox.

Comment: С помощью регулярки я искал слово, которое нужно подсветить.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, другой способ, который будет работать.

Comment: А если вместо RichTextBox использовать `ScintillaNET`?

Comment: @Qwertiy: А какую проблему это решит? Найти ключевые слова или подсветить их? Вторая проблема прекрасно решается и через RichTextBox.

Comment: Корректура по регулярному выражению: лучше писать так `string pattern = @"\bhello\b";` метасимвол `\b` полностью аналогичен `(\W|^)` но более приятен для глаз.

Comment: @VladD, мне кажется, что обе. Но я не уверен - сам не пользовался этим компонентом.

Comment: "метасимвол \b полностью аналогичен (\W|^) но более приятен для глаз" @ReinRaus, в данном случае эквивалентен, но в общем - нет. Попробуй применить `\b \b` к строке из одного или нескольких пробелов (кроме пробелов в строке ничего нет). Сравни с `(^|\W) (\W|$)`

Comment: @ReinRaus: Написал-таки парсер, как и обещал. Кстати, на регулярках :-) Реимплементация lex'а вручную.

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685644/highlight-text-in-richtextbox

Answer (score 20):

Итак, для начала, регулярные выражения. Их *можно* использовать для токенизации, но тем не менее парсинг и разбор текста программы не должен быть частью UI-уровня. Поэтому наш код должен отдавать текст на разбор модельному уровню, желательно асинхронно.

Для этого определим сначала вспомогательные типы:

```
enum TokenType { Ident, Comment, Keyword, Punct, String, Number }

class QualifiedToken
{
    public TokenType Type;
    public TextPointer StartPosition;
    public int StartOffset;
    public TextPointer EndPosition;
    public int EndOffset;
}

class RawText
{
    public string Text;
    public TextPointer Start;
}
```

и класс с простейшим публичным интерфейсом:

```
class Lexer
{
    public static Task<List<QualifiedToken>> Parse(IEnumerable<RawText> texts)
    {
        var lexer = new Lexer(texts);
        return Task.Run(() => lexer.Parse().ToList());
    }

    // имплементация
}
```

Мы должны передавать `TextPointer` внутрь, поскольку иначе мы рискуем потерять точную позицию распознанного токена в документе. Точно так же мы возвращаем результат, адресуя его через смещение относительно `TextPointer`'а.

Собирать тексты довольно просто: `GetParagraphs(doc.Blocks).ToList()`, где `GetParagraphs` рекурсивно обходит документ:

```
IEnumerable<Paragraph> GetParagraphs(BlockCollection blockCollection)
{
    foreach (var block in blockCollection)
    {
        var para = block as Paragraph;
        if (para != null)
        {
            yield return para;
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var innerPara in GetParagraphs(block.SiblingBlocks))
                yield return innerPara;
        }
    }
}
```

Каждый абзац — самостоятельная часть текста, их можно обрабатывать вместе или по отдельности:

```
async Task UpdateParagraph(Paragraph par)
{
    var completeTextRange = new TextRange(par.ContentStart, par.ContentEnd);
    completeTextRange.ClearAllProperties();
    await UpdateInlines(par.Inlines);
}

async Task UpdateAllParagraphs(IEnumerable<Paragraph> paragraphs)
{
    var materialParagraphs = paragraphs.ToList();
    if (materialParagraphs.Count == 0)
        return;
    var completeTextRange = new TextRange(materialParagraphs.First().ContentStart,
                                          materialParagraphs.Last().ContentEnd);
    completeTextRange.ClearAllProperties();
    await UpdateInlines(materialParagraphs.SelectMany(par => par.Inlines));
}

async Task UpdateInlines(IEnumerable<Inline> inlines)
{
    var texts = ExtractText(inlines);
    var positionsAndBrushes =
        (from qualifiedToken in await Lexer.Parse(texts)
         let brush = GetBrushForTokenType(qualifiedToken.Type)
         where brush != null
         let start = qualifiedToken.StartPosition
                                   .GetPositionAtOffset(qualifiedToken.StartOffset)
         let end = qualifiedToken.EndPosition
                                 .GetPositionAtOffset(qualifiedToken.EndOffset)
         let position = new TextRange(start, end)
         select new { position, brush }).ToList();

    foreach (var pb in positionsAndBrushes)
        pb.position.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, pb.brush);
}
```

(нам пришлось материализовать список позиций, так как применение атрибутов инвалидирует смещения)

Вспомогательные методы для `ExtractText` скучны и бесхитростны, они отслеживают `Run`'ы и `LineBreak`'и:

```
IEnumerable<RawText> ExtractText(IEnumerable<Inline> inlines)
{
    return inlines.SelectMany(ExtractText);
}

IEnumerable<RawText> ExtractText(Inline inline)
{
    return ExtractTextImpl((dynamic)inline);
}

IEnumerable<RawText> ExtractTextImpl(Run run)
{
    return new[] { new RawText() { Text = run.Text, Start = run.ContentStart } };
}

IEnumerable<RawText> ExtractTextImpl(LineBreak br)
{
    return new[] { new RawText() { Text = "\n", Start = br.ContentStart } };
}

IEnumerable<RawText> ExtractTextImpl(Span span)
{
    return ExtractText(span.Inlines);
}

IEnumerable<RawText> ExtractTextImpl(Inline inline)
{
    return Enumerable.Empty<RawText>();
}
```

[Для более современного C# 8 можно использовать более лаконичную форму:

```
IEnumerable<RawText> ExtractText(IEnumerable<Inline> inlines) =>
    inlines.SelectMany(inline => inline switch
        {
            Run run => new[] { new RawText() { Text = run.Text, Start = run.ContentStart } },
            LineBreak br => new[] { new RawText() { Text = "\n", Start = br.ContentStart } },
            Span span => ExtractText(span.Inlines),
            _ => Enumerable.Empty<RawText>()
        });
```

с сопоставлением шаблонов.]

В итоге получаем вот такую раскраску:

[image: а вот и результат]

Лексер сам по себе практически тривиален. Должен правильно понимать числа, строки и комментарии.

```
class Lexer
{
    public static Task<List<QualifiedToken>> Parse(IEnumerable<RawText> texts)
    {
        var lexer = new Lexer(texts);
        return Task.Run(() => lexer.Parse().ToList());
    }

    List<int> partIndices = new List<int>();
    List<TextPointer> pointers = new List<TextPointer>();
    string totalText;

    Lexer(IEnumerable<RawText> texts)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var text in texts)
        {
            partIndices.Add(sb.Length);
            sb.Append(text.Text);
            pointers.Add(text.Start);
        }
        totalText = sb.ToString();
    }

    Tuple<TextPointer, int> GetBasePointerAndOffset(int position)
    {
        var partNo = partIndices.BinarySearch(position);
        if (partNo < 0)
            partNo = ~partNo - 1;
        var partStart = partIndices[partNo];
        var delta = position - partStart;
        return Tuple.Create(pointers[partNo], delta);
    }

    static Regex combineRegex(Dictionary<string, string> name2pattern)
    {
        var combinedRegexParts =
                "^(" +
                string.Join("|", name2pattern.Select(
                       kvp => string.Format("(?<{0}>{1})", kvp.Key, kvp.Value))) +
                ")";
        return new Regex(combinedRegexParts,
                         RegexOptions.Compiled |
                           RegexOptions.Multiline |
                           RegexOptions.Singleline);
    }

    static Lexer()
    {
        var numPatternWithoutSign = @"(\d+(\.\d*)?)|(\.\d+)";
        var numPatternWithSign = @"[+-]?" + numPatternWithoutSign;

        var regexParts = new Dictionary<string, string>()
        {
            { "ident",   @"\p{L}\w*" },
            { "num",     numPatternWithSign },
            { "comment", @"(/\*.*?\*/)|(//.*?$)" },
            { "punct",   @"(:=)|(<=)|(>=)|(==)|[;+\-\*/\(\){}:<>=]" },
            { "string",  "\"[^\"\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^\"\\\\]*)*\"" },
            { "space",   @"\s+" }
        };

        recognizer = combineRegex(regexParts);

        regexParts["num"] = numPatternWithoutSign;
        recognizerWithoutSignedNumbers = combineRegex(regexParts);

        names = regexParts.Keys;
    }

    static Regex recognizer, recognizerWithoutSignedNumbers;
    static IEnumerable<string> names;
    static Dictionary<string, TokenType?> tokenMapping =
        new Dictionary<string, TokenType?>()
        {
            { "ident", TokenType.Ident },
            { "num", TokenType.Number },
            { "comment", TokenType.Comment },
            { "punct", TokenType.Punct },
            { "string",  TokenType.String },
            { "space", null }
        };

    IEnumerable<QualifiedToken> Parse()
    {
        string restLine = totalText;
        int currPos = 0;
        TokenType? lastSignigicantToken = null;

        while (restLine != "")
        {
            bool allowSignedNumber = lastSignigicantToken == TokenType.Punct;
            var match = (allowSignedNumber ? recognizer : recognizerWithoutSignedNumbers)
                .Match(restLine);
            var nameAndGroup =
                    names.Select(name => new { name, group = match.Groups[name] })
                         .Single(ng => ng.group.Success);

            var text = nameAndGroup.group.Value;
            var length = nameAndGroup.group.Length;

            var tokenType = tokenMapping[nameAndGroup.name];
            if (tokenType == TokenType.Ident && CheckKeyword(text))
                tokenType = TokenType.Keyword;

            if (tokenType != null)
            {
                var start = GetBasePointerAndOffset(currPos);
                var end = GetBasePointerAndOffset(currPos + length);
                yield return new QualifiedToken()
                                 {
                                     Type = tokenType.Value,
                                     StartPosition = start.Item1,
                                     StartOffset = start.Item2,
                                     EndPosition = end.Item1,
                                     EndOffset = end.Item2
                                 };
            }

            if (tokenType != null && tokenType != TokenType.Comment)
                lastSignigicantToken = tokenType;

            currPos += length;
            restLine = restLine.Substring(length);
        }
    }

    static HashSet<string> keywords = new HashSet<string>()
    {
        "for",
        "while",
        "int",
        "string",
        "bool"
    };

    bool CheckKeyword(string text)
    {
        return keywords.Contains(text);
    }
}
```

Если кому интересно, вот тестовый проект: https://github.com/vladd/Simple-Lexer

---

Обновление: По итогам дискуссии с @ReinRaus исправил лексер для правильного различения случаев числа со знаком и бинарного оператора:

[image: исправленный лексер]

Comment: Очень-очень круто. Не зря я Вас приглашал :) Спасибо.

Comment: @ReinRaus: И вам спасибо! Кстати, вы не могли бы глянуть на регулярки ([тут](http://pastebin.com/4FVsJSWA)), они скорее всего далеки от идеала?

Comment: Я не сразу все посмотрю, **num** - посмотрите http://refiddle.com/refiddles/55547ca075622d5b8e7c0200 возможно некоторые конструкции не разрешены синтаксисом. Например `-.345` а я их включил в регулярное выражение

Comment: @ReinRaus: [`-.345`](http://ideone.com/Cc6uIt) должно по идее работать. Вопрос, кстати, хороший, как парсить `-.345`: это унарный минус + выражение, состоящее из числа `.345`, или одно число?

Comment: @ReinRaus: Уфф! Понял конструкцию `(?:(?<!\d[\t ]*)[+-])?`. Она отлавливает случай `5 + 5`, правильно? Но на самом деле, наверное нужно отловить и `a + 5` или там вообще `(a) + 5`. Может быть, правильнее будет отказаться от `[+-]`, и считать это унарным/бинарным минусом/плюсом, а не частью числа?

Comment: Наверно нужно смотреть не только наличие числа, но и также символа, скобок (любых) и операторов

Comment: @ReinRaus: Спасибо!

Comment: @ReinRaus: Плюс надо смотреть «сквозь» комментарии. Думаю, подойдёт следующее правило: если предыдущий токен, не считая комментарии — пунктуация (`[\.,+-=/\*\(\)\[\]{}~]`), то знак можно считать частью числа. (В лексере как раз известен предыдущий токен.)

Comment: @ReinRaus: Исправил лексер, теперь он понимает числа/бинарные операции правильно.

Comment: Вставляйте код прямо в сообщение, а не ссылайтесь на внешние ресурсы. Сообщения должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки могут служить только дополнением.™

Comment: @VladD а я так понимаю подсветка идет только построчно, если много строчный комментарий, то он не подсветится ?

Comment: @ReinRaus: Подсветка идёт по `Paragraph`'ам. Но многострочные комментарии почему-то не ловит. Это баг, сейчас подправлю.

Comment: @ReinRaus: исправил баг для случая разделения на строки при помощи `\n` или `<LineBreak/>`. На гитхаб пока не внёс (забыл пароль), внесу вечером.

Comment: @ReinRaus: Ага, и проблему с энтерами тоже исправил. Вот апдейт: http://pastebin.com/2NBLwQk2 + новый код с `UpdateAllParagraphs` в вопросе.

Comment: Очешуеть. То есть содержимое RichTextBox может быть не только текст, но и метаданные, вроде `<LineBreak/>` О_о Задача тогда нереально сложна.

Comment: @ReinRaus: Нормально :) Код линеаризует все вложенные метаблоки, игнорируя картинки и вложенные UI-элементы.

Comment: @ReinRaus: Обновил версию на гитхабе.

Comment: Всё круто, кроме того, что этот код работает чертовски медленно, и такую подсветку нельзя применять для редактора, который будет подсвечивать код в реальном времени.

Comment: @NightmareZ: Ну собственно этот код и задумывался как proof of concept. Если вы хотите realtime-поведения, вам придётся его существенно доработать до коммерческого состояния. Например, перекрашивать текст до точки изменения смысла не имеет. Затем, если вы не находитесь внутри многострочного комментария, то перекрашивать код в строках ниже точки изменения также не имеет смысла. Вам придётся, да, делать много подобных оптимизаций, я с этим не заморачивался.

Comment: @NightmareZ: Собственно, относительно «большая» перекраска нужна лишь в случае, если вы добавляете или убираете символы `/*` или `*/` (или там убираете добавляете/убираете символы между `/` и `*`. В случае `"` можно ограничиться текущей строкой. В остальных случаях изменения, кажется, вообще локальны.

Comment: @VladD , я примерно неделю занимался улучшением кода и всякими оптимизациями. В итоге всё работает хорошо, в том числе и многострочные комментарии, и перерисовывается только то, что изменилось, но приемлемой производительности мне всё же достичь не удалось... во всяком случае, на основе RichTextBox.

Comment: @NightmareZ: Понимаю. Тогда, возможно, вам стоит подумать о собственном рендеринге текста? Я помню обсуждения на ru.SO по этому поводу.

Comment: @NightmareZ: Посмотрите, может быть этот путь кастомного рендеринга текстов пройдёт. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427492/10105 Но это недешёвый путь. Вот ещё по теме высокопроизводительного рендеринга: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/776235/10105

Answer (score 9):

`RichTextBox` плохо совместим с подходом "найти позиции совпадений, их длину и подсветить".

Решение влоб  - найти позиции символов через `Match.Index`/`Match.Length` не срабатвает по причине несовпадения понятий "символ" и "смещение" в регулярных выражениях и в `TextRange`.

Для `Regex` смещение (*index*) - это позиция символа (*character*) в строке - количество симолов от начала строки и до текущего символа.

Для метода поиска позиции по смещению - `TextRange.GetPositionAtOffset` вместо индекса используется смещение (*offset*. Который измеряется в количестве символов (*symbol*). При этом символами считаются:

> - открывающий или закрывающий тэг элемнта TextElement
> - UIElement содержащийся в InlineUIContainer or BlockUIContainer. Этот элемент всегда считается ровно одним символом, вне зависимости от его содержимого или внутренних элементов
> - 16-битный символ Unicode внутри текстового элемента Run

С точки зрения `Regex` только последнее из этого списка является символом. Поэтому все остальное надо выбрасывать при обработке:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    string pattern = @"(\W|^)hello(\W|$)";
    Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

    var allText = new TextRange(richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart, richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd);
    allText.ClearAllProperties();

    var start = richTextBox1.Document.ContentStart;
    while (start != null && start.CompareTo(richTextBox1.Document.ContentEnd) < 0)
    {
        if (start.GetPointerContext(LogicalDirection.Forward) == TextPointerContext.Text)
        {
            var match = regex.Match(start.GetTextInRun(LogicalDirection.Forward));

            var textrange = new TextRange(start.GetPositionAtOffset(match.Index, LogicalDirection.Forward), start.GetPositionAtOffset(match.Index + match.Length, LogicalDirection.Backward));
            textrange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue));
            textrange.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Bold);
            start = textrange.End; 
        }
        start = start.GetNextContextPosition(LogicalDirection.Forward);
    }
}
```

<sub>очень сильно по мотивам [ответа на enSO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5685644/c-sharp-wpf-highlight-text-in-richtextbox/5690368#5690368)</sub>

Comment: А почему `ApplyPropertyValue`?

Comment: @VladD а почему бы и нет? для меня wpf-хобби, я сделал как нашел (а ищется везде именно через ApplyPropertyValue. да и еще с кривым расчетом позиции :() если можете подправить - подправьте)

Comment: Ну, если вы пишете код, вы как бы отвечаете за него. Просто это довольно экзотический метод устанавливать значение `DependencyProperty`, вот я и переспросил.

Comment: @VladD а какие еще есть варианты для `TextRange`?

Comment: Хм, посмотрел внутрь. Оказывается, там нету property `Foreground`, так что это и правда остаётся единственным законным путём. Странно!