# Как использовать TextFormatter?

Tags: c#, wpf, текст

Решил использовать [TextFormatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.textformatting.textformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) для реализации редактируемого поля для форматированного текста (гарнитура, размер фрагментов текста и т.п.). Но нашёл только [статью в документации на MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/vstudio/ms754036%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) об этом API. Не сказал бы, что мне стало всё понятно. Ни в одной, из имеющихся у меня книг по WPF (М.МакДональд, Ч.Петцольд, А.Натан, "WPF Cookbook", А.Троелсен) об этом даже не упоминается. В связи с этим может быть кто-то знает какой-нибудь источник, где можно подробнее почитать про применение TextFormattter'а? Или может быть, кто-нибудь может привести небольшой пример программы? Буду очень благодарен за помощь.

UPD: Моя задача заключается в написании *текстового редактора* с поддержкой форматирования (гарнитура, размер отдельных фрагментов текста), в том числе должна быть каретка для навигации по тексту. И выделение фрагмента текста с возможностью копирования этого фрагмента. Ну и вставка какого-нибудь текста. Но преподаватель запретил использовать готовые контролы (типа TextBox, RichTextBox). Хотел применить FlowDocuement, но и это не разрешили. Мол, надо все самому реализовать. Вот теперь и ищу, как можно в WPF прорисовывать текст, но с поддержкой его редактирования.

Comment: Это достаточно низкоуровневая штука, обычно вам не нужно спускаться в такие дебри. Чем вам не подходит обычный `TextBox`? Расскажите вашу [настоящую задачу](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). А пример на `TextFormatter` есть в [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.textformatting.textformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Ок, задача заключается в написании текстового редактора с поддержкой форматирования (гарнитура, размер отдельных фрагментов текста), в том числе должна быть каретка для навигации по тексту. И выделение фрагмента текста с возможностью копирования этого фрагмента. Ну и вставка какого-нибудь текста. Но преподаватель запретил использовать готовые контролы (типа TextBox, RichTextBox). Хотел применить FlowDocuement, но и это не разрешили. Мол, надо все самому реализовать. Вот теперь и ищу, как можно в WPF прорисовывать текст, но с поддержкой его редактирования.

Comment: Пример из документации, честно говоря, не до конца ясен. Хотелось бы больше пояснений к нему. У меня совсем нет опыта.:(

Comment: Ууууууух. Ну и задание у вас. Вот это велосипедище.

Comment: Ага, не очень удачно. У других были ещё графовый или графический редакторы. А мне текстовый достался. Графовый интереснее всего, по-моему.) Да и там проще с реализацией (по крайней мере на WPF).

Comment: Ну, у текста есть куча интересных проблем. Например, можно имплементировать Кнутовский алгоритм [разбиения на строки](http://defoe.sourceforge.net/folio/knuth-plass.html) (существенно лучше, чем стандартный из MS Office).

Comment: Для начала надо хотя бы основные простейшие требования выполнить. TextFormatter для этого - то что нужно? И если да, есть ли ещё какие-нибудь источники, кроме MSDN, где можно почитать о нём подробнее?

Comment: Да, думаю, TextFormatter — это именно то. Кроме MSDN, боюсь, других ресурсов нет. Но там есть полный пример (я привёл ссылку в ответе), вы можете использовать его в качестве отправной точки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Итак, для чего нужен `TextFormatter`? Он нужен для того, чтобы вручную, без применения стандартных контролов, разбить текст на строки, и вычислить различные layout-параметры наподобие суммарной высоты и глубины от базовой линии, свисания фрагментов текста за bounding box, и тому подобные штуки, нужные если вы собираетесь делать layout вручную. Вам наверняка стоит почитать [документацию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754036%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) и разобраться. Может быть, вам пригодится [Microsoft Typography](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Typography/default.aspx), и/или какая-нибудь книга по типографике.

Весь пример кода с посторонними классами лежит [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms771407%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Текст примера на самом деле очень прост:

```
// создаём рабочий объект
TextFormatter formatter = TextFormatter.Create();

// и его параметры
CustomTextParagraphProperties customTextParagraphProperties
    = new CustomTextParagraphProperties();

// теперь разобьём текст на строки
// для этого в цикле смотрим, сколько у нас ещё осталось необработанных
// символов
// textStorePosition -- это номер первого необработанного символа,
// customTextSource.Text -- строка
while (textStorePosition < customTextSource.Text.Length)
{
    // создаём объект TextLine, содержащий отформатированную строку
    using (TextLine myTextLine = formatter.FormatLine(
        customTextSource,  // объект TextSource (см. документацию)
        textStorePosition, // начинать с этого символа
        96 * 6,            // ширина строки
        customTextParagraphProperties, // этот объект задаёт форматирование
        null))
    {
        // отобразить TextLine. (это можно сделать и позже)
        myTextLine.Draw(drawingContext, linePosition, InvertAxes.None);

        // в myTextLine.Length лежит к-во символов, которые поместились
        // в ширину. остальные надо дообработать
        textStorePosition += myTextLine.Length;

        // следующую строку надо рисовать ниже
        linePosition.Y += myTextLine.Height;
    }
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за  ответ! Поставил бы "+", если бы репутация позволяла.) А что из себя представляет TextSource? Так, простыми словами. А то в принципе данную модель не понимаю.

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Ну, `TextSource` — это такая штука, которая знает, что символы с 0 по 5 — один блок, набирается одним шрифтом, символы с 6 по 24 — другой блок, другим шрифтом и т. д. Ничего особенного, по идее.

Comment: @Dark_Clark: То есть `TextSource` вам придётся самостоятельно реализовывать, он же абстрактный.

Comment: О, отлично тогда. И правда, то что нужно. А то я сначала пытался работать с FormattedText на Canvas. Пока ничего, кроме вывода текста по нажатию клавиш не получалось.)

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Вот тут вроде бы расписано по шагам. Но вы попробуйте для начала скачать пример и адаптировать его.

Comment: Да, буду разбираться. Спасибо большое, ещё раз! :) А то уже долго топчусь на одном месте. Теперь хотя бы более менее понял принципе данной модели. Однако не исключаю появления новых вопросов.

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Проходите с вопросами, разберёмся :) Пожалуйста!

Comment: А вот и первый вопрос: что за [TextSpan<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms607025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (встречается как тип возвращаемого методом TextSource.GetPrecedingText(...) значения)? Каково его назначение? И там ещё в теле переопределения этого метода встречаются CultureSpecificCharacterBufferRange и CharacterBufferRange. Тоже не могу понять, что это за класс и структура. В документации почти ничего нет (там, конечно, есть описание размером в одно предложение, но мне не хватило этого, чтобы понять назначение).
P.S.: В примере можно найти в переопределении класса TextSource.

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Смотрите. Сам по себе `TextSpan` представляет собой просто набор из данных и длины в символах строкового представления этих данных. То есть например какой-то ваш внутренний объект, представляющий кусок текста с форматированием, и длина текста в символах. Вам им пользоваться не нужно, но вам нужно будет выдать его в `GetPrecedingText` (то есть по существу сконструировать). Для `GetPrecedingText` вам нужен конкретный `T = CultureSpecificCharacterBufferRange`, который содержит просто текст и язык.

Comment: @Dark_Clark: `CharacterBufferRange` — это обёртка на кусок текста: строка, начальный и конечный индекс. Нужен, чтобы не плодить подстроки (исключительно для эффективности, т. к. может быть _очень_ много подстрок).

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Вам `TextSpan<>` нуженб только чтобы сконструировать его в вашей имплементации `TextSource`: вам нужно найти предыдущий кусок текста (насколько я помню, это кусок текста с одними и теми же атрибутами: шрифтом, наколом, жирностью и т. п.), обернуть его в буфер и выдать.

Comment: То есть, судя по [описанию в документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms607025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `TextSpan` может хранить любой объект, не обязательно текст... Так ведь? И когда используются методы `GetPrecedingText`, `GetTextRun`?

Comment: И также не понял, для чего нужно переопределять метод [GetTextEffectCharacterIndexFromTextSourceCharacterIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.textformatting.textsource.gettexteffectcharacterindexfromtextsourcecharacterindex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? Что должно быть в его теле? В примере он не определён, просто выбрасывает исключение с сообщением, что он не реализован.

Comment: Уж простите, что терроризирую вопросами, но мне больше негде спросить. В документации как-то совсем мало. А преподаватель сам джавист, в .NET, особенно в таких дебрях, как этот TextFormatter, не разбирается. :( Было бы это где-нибудь описано, как в книгах, изучил бы. А тут даже в интернете информации не нашёл. Никаких гайдов, ничего.

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Да, в принципе он может хранить любой объект. Но вам интересен только случай с `CultureSpecificCharacterBufferRange` по сути. Методы `GetPrecedingText` и `GetTextRun` используются механизмом разбиения на строки (`formatter.FormatLine`), вам их вызывать не придётся. `GetTextEffectCharacterIndexFromTextSourceCharacterIndex` нужен только если у вас используются какие-то эффекты (наподобие вращающегося текста), вам это покамест не нужно, так что можно по идее оставить исключение.

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Всё в порядке, спрашивайте. Я тоже занимался этим всего пару недель, так что вряд ли смогу ответить на особо сложные вопросы. Ваше задание очень специфическое, вряд ли кто-то сталкивался с подобным.

Comment: Ещё вот что интересует. В примере текст для помещения в `TextSource` берётся из `TextBox`'а, затем обрабатывается `Formatter`'ом, после чего результат выводится как 2D-рисунок. Но для текстового редактора это как-то неправильно было бы.) В общем, как бы так без использования `TextBox`'а передавать текст прямо в `Formatter`? Да так, чтобы потом можно было изменять его, выделяя прямо в поле вывода? Просто при обработке события ввода с клавиатуры и при команде вставки из буфера обмена? Короче говоря, как всё это свести к одному рабочему полю?

Comment: И как добавить каретку? Самому полностью реализовать? Или есть возможно использовать уже существующую?

Comment: @Dark_Clark: ну, вам придётся иметь свой собственный `CustomTextSource`. Это именно то место, где путь вашей имплементации расходится с примером. И вы берёте текст не из `TextBlock`'а, а из собственной структуры данных, описывающей текст и его атрибуты. По сути, вам нужно будет продублировать объекты типа `Span`, `Run` и т. п. у себя. (Я бы не советовал делать `Bold`, просто `Span` с атрибутами форматирования.)

Comment: @Dark_Clark: По поводу каретки всё кисло. Есть дав пути. Либо вы пользуетесь системной кареткой (мы можете это сделать, но придётся использовать WinAPI и P/Invoke напрямую), либо рисовать вручную, добавляя и убирая на таймере и перемещая, когда нужно. Choose your poison.

Comment: Ох, спасибо большое. Ещё хватает гемороя впереди... 

А что лучше взять в качестве поле для отображения текста? `Canvas`?

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Угу, проще всего Canvas наверное. Впрочем, если вы решите остальные проблемы, эта будет самой маленькой.

Comment: Ладно, большое спасибо за помощь. Чуть что, буду ещё писать сюда.

Comment: А вот вы ещё писали, что занимались данной темой пару недель. Может быть тогда остался какой-то пример реализации `TextSource`, более сложный, чем в примере?

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Я посмотрю только в пятницу, завтра у меня выходной (а дома ничего не обнаружилось).

Comment: Ок, было бы отлично. Но вы и так мне очень помогли! Спасибо!

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Вместо обновления вопроса лучше добавить отдельный вопрос. Обновления в вопросе, на который уже дан и принят ответ, скорее всего никто не будет читать.

Comment: Ок, спасибо. Послушался вашего совета.)

Comment: Ещё вопрос.) Для чего вообще передавать число в конструкторы классов `TextEndOfLine` и `TextEndOfParagraph`? Что вообще эти классы из себя представляют? Просто метки для `TextFormatter`'а, по которым он определяет, прерывать текст как строку или как абзац?

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Ну, вам ведь надо для каждого куска текста точно знать, сколько он занимает, чтобы суметь по индексу символа найти текст. А логический конец строки может занимать сколько угодно символов. Например, один (`\n`). Или два (`\r\n`). Или может у вас ещё какое-нибудь представление, кто ж его заранее знает? Так что, чтобы не загонять вас в правило «конец строки = ровно один символ», у вас и спрашивают точное количество.

Comment: Да, понял. Близко к этому и представлял себе. Только вот где указывать этот формат (последовательность символов) конца строки/абзаца? В `TextEndOfLine` и `TextEndOfParagraph` передаётся ведь только число.

Comment: @Dark_Clark: А это не нужно, по идее. Смотрите, во-первых, у вас есть весь текст в оригинальной строке. Теперь, **для чего** вам нужен кусок текста в `TextRun` (`CharacterBufferReference`)? Лишь для отображения, правильно? Чтобы знать, какие символы нужно нарисовать. Потому что для хранения у нас и так есть строка в модели (то, откуда она обычно приходит в `TextRun`). Но для случая `TextEndOfLine` и так понятно, как его отображать, поэтому сами символы на _этом_ уровне не нужны. (А на уровне, где они реально нужны, они и есть.)

Comment: "_(А на уровне, где они реально нужны, они и есть.)_"

 - Этот уровень - ОС (для Windows - CRLF, для Linux - LF и т.д.)? Я правильно понял?

Comment: Скорее, это уровень модели в вашей программе. Для отображения всё равно, как именно у вас в файле закодирован конец строки. А для уровня модели важно, потому что текст придётся рано или поздно сбрасывать в файл.

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Нашёл свой пример, но он тоже берёт текст из TextBlock'а. (Задача стояла вывести текст из документа в pdf.)

Comment: Спасибо, что посмотрели. Уже и так вроде бы въехал, что делать. Реализовываю объектную модель документа, по аналогии с `FlowDocument` (т.е. работа пользователя будет производится непосредственно с объектом моего документа, который уже будет отправлять запросы `TextFormatter`'у). Затем нужно будет в наследованном от `TextSource` классе в методах `GetTextRun` и `GetPrecedingText` описать логику извлечения различных элементов этой модели. Я правильно понимаю?

Comment: И сразу интересует, как сделать поддержку сохранения документа в общепринятые форматы, типа RTF? Для этого необходимо связать мою модель документа с уже имеющимся в .NET `TextRange`, и уже посредством его методов сохранять/загружать RTF-файл?

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Ну, хм. RichTextBox умеет загрузить в себя rtf, но если вам нельзя им пользоваться...

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Насчёт наследника `TextSource`, именно так.

Comment: Да, нельзя. С RichTextBox'ом выполнить все требования моего задания очень просто. Собственно, это я уже давно сделал.

Comment: Вот поэтому и интересует, возможно ли это сделать как-нибудь через класс `TextRange`. Ведь именно он используется для сохранения и загрузки файлов в RichTextBox.

Comment: @Dark_Clark: А, ну да. `TextRange.Load` работает. Но после этого вам нужно будет прочитать его объектную модель и перебросить данные в свою. Или если ваша модель основана на TextRange, то вообще ничего делать не надо :)

Comment: @Dark_Clark: В качестве формата используйте [`DataFormats.Rtf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dataformats.rtf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: _"...если ваша модель основана на TextRange..."_ - А вот отсюда, пожалуйста, поподробнее, если можно.) Есть способ "основать" модель на `TextRange`'е?

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Ну, если основным хранителем данных у вас в модели является `TextRange`, например. А если свой собственный класс, то конечно придётся данные доставать из `TextRange` (по идее, не так сложно) и перекладывать в собственные классы.

Comment: То есть в каждом элементе модели (`Run`, `Span` и т.д.) имеется свойство типа `TextRange`, в свойстве `Text` которого хранится сама текстовая строка, относящаяся к данному элементу? Ну и соответственно, в свойствах `TextRange.Start` и `TextRange.End` хранятся начало и конец элемента? Как-то так?

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Как именно там внутри, я не знаю. Но у любого объекта, производного от `Inline`, есть `TextPointer`'ы `ContentStart` + `ContentEnd`, из которых можно построить `TextRange`. Range, судя по всему, это просто указатель на начало/конец текста (где? не знаю точно).

Comment: Ладно, спасибо (уже в который раз). :) Буду разбираться.

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Пожалуйста! Удачи!

Comment: Добрый вечер. Решил обратиться с вопросом ещё раз тут, т.к. объяснять суть долго не придётся. В оф. примере текст рисуется как заливка прямоугольника через объект `DrawingBrush`. Не знаю, нормальное ли это решение, но, по крайней мере, обновлять текст удобно. Но я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: не знаю, как добавить полосу прокрутки, когда объём текста превышает размеры поля (у меня это не Rectangle, а Canvas). Пробовал использовать `ScrollViewer`, но что-то не вышло. Возможно, из-за того, что в Canvas'е текст - не его внутренний элемент, а просто кисть. Не подскажете, как это разрешить?

Comment: @Dark_Clark: ScrollViewer — это правильный вариант для прокрутки, по идее. А как построено ваше дерево объектов? По идее, вы должны поместить Canvas в ScrolViewer, и изменять размер Canvas'а, чтобы он соответствовал размеру «нарисованного» текста. (Этот размер вы точно знаете, он вам доступен в процессе отрисовки.) Тогда скроллбар будет появляться автоматически.

Comment: Да, точно. Чего-то не додумался изменять размер Canvas'a по мере увеличения текста в ручную. Спасибо за подсказку.

Comment: @Dark_Clark: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

На главном Stackoverflow нашёл [ответ по поводу TextFormatter'a](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3194366/4937047). Вот решил и здесь поделиться ссылкой.) Собственно, многое из того, что там объясняется, уже есть здесь в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/427492/182556) (и комментариях к нему), который оставил [VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd). Там тоже за основу взят стандартный пример, но он немного модифицирован.