# WPF, Text Formatter API - Пример реализации абстрактного класса TextSource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, редактор-текста

Данный вопрос тесно связан с [этим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/427476/182556). Но ещё раз вкратце о **реальной задаче**: реализую текстовый редактор с поддержкой форматирования текста (выделение фрагмента текста, изменение гарнитуры его шрифта, размера и т.п.). Для решения сей задачи выбрал [Text Formatter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.textformatting.textformatter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Сейчас же меня интересует реализация текстового хранилища, для чего надо наследовать и реализовать абстрактный класс `TextSource`. Чтобы разобраться, как это сделать, хотелось бы увидеть какие-то примеры. Желательно, более сложные, нежели в [официальном примере](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms771407%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Comment: Ответ получил [здесь](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cca97535-8543-4465-8981-ba02ba453e8c/advanced-text-formatting-examples?forum=wpf#cca97535-8543-4465-8981-ba02ba453e8c).

Comment: Проголосовал за переоткрытие вопроса. Если его переоткроют, опубликуете как ответ?

Comment: @VladD, Добрый вечер. Да, без проблем. Недавно заметил, что вопрос закрыли.

Comment: Открыто,  можно отвечать)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ на вопрос получил на форуме MSDN - [ссылка](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cca97535-8543-4465-8981-ba02ba453e8c/advanced-text-formatting-examples?forum=wpf#cca97535-8543-4465-8981-ba02ba453e8c). Код примера привожу ниже:

```
class SampleTextSource : TextSource
{
    string text = "Foo Bar\nNext Line";

    List<Span> spans = new List<Span> {
        new Span { Start = 0, Length = 3, Color = Brushes.Blue },
        new Span { Start = 3, Length = 1, Color = Brushes.Black },
        new Span { Start = 4, Length = 3, Color = Brushes.Red },
        new Span { Start = 7, Length = 1, Color = Brushes.Black },
        new Span { Start = 8, Length = 4, Color = Brushes.Green },
        new Span { Start = 12, Length = 5, Color = Brushes.Black },
    };

    class Span
    {
        public int Start;
        public int Length;
        public Brush Color;

        public bool Contains(int index)
        {
            return Start <= index && index < Start + Length;
        }
    }

    public int Length
    {
        get { return text.Length; }
    }

    public override TextRun GetTextRun(int textSourceCharacterIndex)
    {
        var span = spans.Find(s => s.Contains(textSourceCharacterIndex));

        if (span == null)
            return new TextEndOfParagraph(1);

        if (span.Length == 1 && text[span.Start] == '\n')
            return new TextEndOfLine(1);

        return new TextCharacters(text, span.Start, span.Length, new SampleTextRunProperties(span.Color));
    }

    public override TextSpan<CultureSpecificCharacterBufferRange> GetPrecedingText(int textSourceCharacterIndexLimit)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override int GetTextEffectCharacterIndexFromTextSourceCharacterIndex(int textSourceCharacterIndex)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

class SampleTextRunProperties : TextRunProperties
{
    private readonly Brush foregroundBrush;

    public SampleTextRunProperties(Brush foregroundBrush)
    {
        this.foregroundBrush = foregroundBrush;
    }
    ...реализация остальных необходимых свойств (можно взять из SDK-примера)
}

class SampleTextParagraphProperties : TextParagraphProperties
{
    ...реализация остальных необходимых свойств (можно взять из SDK-примера)
}

class SampleTextElement : UIElement
{
    protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
    {
        TextFormatter text = TextFormatter.Create();
        SampleTextSource source = new SampleTextSource();
        SampleTextParagraphProperties paraProps = new SampleTextParagraphProperties();
        int index = 0;
        double y = 0.0;

        while (index < source.Length)
        {
            TextLine line = text.FormatLine(source, index, RenderSize.Width, paraProps, null);
            line.Draw(drawingContext, new Point(0.0, y), InvertAxes.None);
            index += line.Length;
            y += line.TextHeight;
        }
    }
}
```

SDK-пример можно скачать [здесь](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms771407%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Если необходимо, чтобы текст отображался с переносом (а это зачастую и требуется), то нужно, во-первых, в реализации `TextParagraphProperties` переопределить свойство `TextWrapping`, а во-вторых, в реализации метода `TextRun GetTextRun(int textSourceCharacterIndex)` в последнем выражении return использовать следующий фрагмент кода, вместо выше приведённого:

```
return new TextCharacters(text, textSourceCharacterIndex, span.Length - (textSourceCharacterIndex - span.Start), new SampleTextRunProperties(span.Color));
```

Это делается для поддержки возможности разбивать span на несколько строк.