# Изменение цвета вводимого текста (подсветка синтаксиса и ошибок в WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

Хочу написать небольшой редактор кода на WPF. Нужно реализовать подсветку синтаксиса вводимого текста и подчеркивание ошибок на ходу, т. е. во время ввода.

Так вот собственно вопрос: каким инструментом лучше воспользоваться? В стандартном `TextBox` такого не сделать, да и `RichTextBox` тоже не очень подходит по-моему (нет?). Есть ли еще какие-то инструменты для этого? Как лучше реализовать данную задумку?

Comment: Вот вам пример кода: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423654/10105

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужен именно редактор кода, то советую воспользоваться **AvalonEdit**, который используется в IDE SharpDevelop. SharpDevelop — полноценная среда разработки, поэтому у вас не должно возникнуть проблем с добавлением нужных вам возможностей.

- [Сайт AvalonEdit](http://avalonedit.net/)
- [Исходники на GitHub](https://github.com/icsharpcode/AvalonEdit)

Comment: Спасибо, очень полезная вещь. Но все же, будучи начинающим программистом, хотелось бы попробовать самому написать что-то небольшое, а не использовать уже готовый вариант.

Comment: @AlexD. Вы, конечно, можете поиграться с RichTextBox, как с единственным контролом, который вам хоть как-то может помочь, но вы вряд ли добьётесь полноценного функционала. Это сложная задача, на коленке её полноценно не решить. ИМХО.