# DrawingVisual в фоновом потоке С# WPF 3.5

Tags: c#, wpf

В фоновом потоке формирую матрицу случайными числами:

```
public void Step()
{
    Point p;
    Brush b;
    Random r = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < mh; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < mw; j++)
        {
            p = new Point(i*5, j*5);
            int ch = r.Next(0, 100);
            if (ch <= 33)
            {
                b = Brushes.Green;
                vl.Add(new VisualList(p, b));
            }
            else if (ch > 66)
            {
                b = Brushes.Red;
                vl.Add(new VisualList(p, b));
            }
            else
            {
                b = Brushes.Yellow;
                vl.Add(new VisualList(p, b));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

И пытаюсь ее отрисовать с помощью DrawingVisual:

```
private void Print()
{
    visual = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < vl.Count; i++)
        {
            VisualList vlist = vl[i];
            Brush brush = Brushes.Black;
            dc.DrawRectangle(vlist.Brushd, null, new Rect(vlist.Pointd, new Size(4, 4)));
        }
    }
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
    {
        drawingSurface.AddVisual(visual);
    }));
}
```

В итоге получаю ошибку: Необработанное исключение типа "System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException" в mscorlib.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Адресат вызова создал исключение.
Как из фонового потока рисовать на форме?

Полный код

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace matrix
{
/// <summary>
///     Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    const int mh = 200;
    const int mw = 100;
    bool Stop = true;
    DrawingVisual visual;
    List<VisualList> vl = new List<VisualList>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void TestWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread trMatrix = new Thread(Draw);
        trMatrix.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        trMatrix.Start();
    }


    private void Draw()
    {
        while (Stop)
        {
            Step();
            Print();
        }

    }

    private void Print()
    {
        visual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < vl.Count; i++)
            {
                VisualList vlist = vl[i];
                Brush brush = Brushes.Black;
                dc.DrawRectangle(vlist.Brushd, null, new Rect(vlist.Pointd, new Size(4, 4)));
            }
        }
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)(() =>
        {
            drawingSurface.AddVisual(visual);
        }));
    }

    public void Step()
    {
        Point p;
        Brush b;
        Random r = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < mh; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < mw; j++)
            {
                p = new Point(i*5, j*5);
                int ch = r.Next(0, 100);
                if (ch <= 33)
                {
                    b = Brushes.Green;
                    vl.Add(new VisualList(p, b));
                }
                else if (ch > 66)
                {
                    b = Brushes.Red;
                    vl.Add(new VisualList(p, b));
                }
                else
                {
                    b = Brushes.Yellow;
                    vl.Add(new VisualList(p, b));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

public class VisualList
{
    public VisualList(Point pointd, Brush brushd)
    {
        Pointd = pointd;
        Brushd = brushd;
    }

    public Point Pointd
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
    public Brush Brushd
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
}
```

Код класса рисования

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace TestDifferentWpf
{
class DrawingClass : Canvas
{
    private List<Visual> visuals = new List<Visual>();
    protected override int VisualChildrenCount
    {
        get
        {
            return visuals.Count;
        }
    }

    protected override Visual GetVisualChild(int index)
    {
        return visuals[index];
    }

    public void AddVisual(Visual visual)
    {
        visuals.Add(visual);
        base.AddVisualChild(visual);
        base.AddLogicalChild(visual);
    }

    public void DeleteVisual(Visual visual)
    {
        visuals.Remove(visual);
        base.RemoveVisualChild(visual);
        base.RemoveLogicalChild(visual);
    }
}
}
```

XAML

```
<Window x:Name="TestWindow" x:Class="matrix.MainWindow"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestDifferentWpf"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="TestWindow_Loaded">
<Grid Name="gTest">
    <local:DrawingClass x:Name="drawingSurface" Background="White" 
ClipToBounds="True"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Покажите код который вызывает `Print()`

Comment: А можно [mcve]?

Comment: @Bulson добавил полный код.

Comment: @VladD добавил полный код

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет, так, как вы хотите, нельзя: все `FrameworkElement`'ы, которые добавляются друг в друга как `Child`'ы, должны принадлежать одному потоку.

Поэтому так просто рисовать из фонового потока не получится.

Обычно никто не заморачивается и рисует в главном потоке. Но если очень хочется, вам придётся освоить [`PresentationSource`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.presentationsource?view=netframework-4.7.1) и [`VisualTarget`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.visualtarget?view=netframework-4.7.1).

`PresentationSource` — это штука, позволяющая вставить в визуальное дерево какую-то совершенно чужую вещь. А `VisualTarget` позволяет соединять визуальные поддеревья, бегущие в разных потоках.

---

Вот примерная имплементация, которая производит рендеринг в фоновом потоке. Она сделана по этим источникам:

- https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dwayneneed/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual/
- http://gettinggui.com/creating-a-busy-indicator-in-a-separate-thread-in-wpf/

Итак, для начала, заводим нашу имплементацию `PresentationSource`:

```
// https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dwayneneed/2007/04/26/multithreaded-ui-hostvisual/
// https://github.com/higankanshi/Meta.Vlc/blob/master/Meta.Vlc.Wpf
// /VisualTargetPresentationSource.cs
public class VisualTargetPresentationSource : PresentationSource, IDisposable
{
    public VisualTargetPresentationSource(HostVisual hostVisual)
    {
        _visualTarget = new VisualTarget(hostVisual);
        AddSource();
    }

    public override Visual RootVisual
    {
        get => _visualTarget.RootVisual;
        set
        {
            Visual oldRoot = _visualTarget.RootVisual;
            _visualTarget.RootVisual = value;
            RootChanged(oldRoot, value);

            if (value is UIElement rootElement)
            {
                rootElement.Measure(new Size(double.PositiveInfinity,
                                             double.PositiveInfinity));
                rootElement.Arrange(new Rect(rootElement.DesiredSize));
            }
        }
    }

    protected override CompositionTarget GetCompositionTargetCore() => _visualTarget;
    public override bool IsDisposed => _isDisposed;

    public void Dispose()
    {
        RemoveSource();
        _isDisposed = true;
    }

    private VisualTarget _visualTarget;
    private bool _isDisposed;
}
```

Остальную функциональность я упаковал в `MainWindow`, но её, вероятно, стоит разбить на вспомогательные классы.

Объяснение по коду. В конструкторе создаётся `HostVisual`, на который «наденется» `VisualTarget` через `VisualTargetPresentationSource`, и добавляется в визуальное дерево. Поскольку стандартные контролы не умеют добавлять `Visual`'ы, мы пользуемся `DrawingClass` из вопроса.

Далее, мы создаём STA-поток, в котором и будет происходить рендеринг поддерева, и запускаем его.

В потоке мы создаём `VisualTargetPresentationSource`. Затем, нам нужно *сначала* создать диспетчер, а *потом* выполнить на нём код, для этого используется трюк с `InvokeAsync`. (`Dispatcher.Run()` — блокирующая функция!)

В коде мы создаём `Random` (*один* раз, а не на каждой итерации), и в цикле вызываем функции `Step` и `Draw` из вопроса. Я немного переписал функции, чтобы они работали не с полями, а с параметрами. Ну и между итерациями я вставил `Task.Delay`, чтобы не гонять вечный холостой цикл.

Вот весь код:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var hv = new HostVisual();
        drawingSurface.AddVisual(hv);
        Thread trMatrix = new Thread(() => Draw(hv)) { IsBackground = true };
        trMatrix.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        trMatrix.Start();
    }

    void Draw(HostVisual outerhv)
    {
        VisualTargetPresentationSource vtps = new VisualTargetPresentationSource(outerhv);
        var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
        dispatcher.InvokeAsync(async () =>
        {
            Random r = new Random();
            while (true)
            {
                var vl = Step(r);
                var visual = Print(vl);
                vtps.RootVisual = visual;
                await Task.Delay(50);
            }
        });
        Dispatcher.Run();
        vtps.Dispose();
    }

    public List<VisualList> Step(Random r)
    {
        const int mh = 200;
        const int mw = 100;

        List<VisualList> vl = new List<VisualList>();

        for (int i = 0; i < mh; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < mw; j++)
            {
                Point p = new Point(i * 5, j * 5);
                int ch = r.Next(0, 3);
                Brush b = ch == 0 ? Brushes.Green :
                          ch == 1 ? Brushes.Yellow :
                          Brushes.Red;
                vl.Add(new VisualList(p, b));
            }
        }

        return vl;
    }

    private Visual Print(List<VisualList> vl)
    {
        var visual = new DrawingVisual();
        using (DrawingContext dc = visual.RenderOpen())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < vl.Count; i++)
            {
                VisualList vlist = vl[i];
                Brush brush = Brushes.Black;
                dc.DrawRectangle(vlist.Brushd, null,
                                 new Rect(vlist.Pointd, new Size(4, 4)));
            }
        }

        return visual;
    }
}
```

Получилось вот что:

[image: убедительная просьба убрать ваших детей от наших голубых экранов]

---

На старой системе пользоваться async/await может быть сложно, вместо этого приходится использовать таймер:

```
public void Draw(HostVisual outerhv)
{
    VisualTargetPresentationSource vtps = new VisualTargetPresentationSource(outerhv);
    var dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
    DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal, dispatcher)
    {
        Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50),
        IsEnabled = true
    };
    Random r = new Random();
    dt.Tick += (o, args) =>
    {
        var vl = Step(r);
        var visual = Print(vl);
        vtps.RootVisual = visual;
    };
    Dispatcher.Run();
    vtps.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72356/discussion-on-answer-by-vladd-drawingvisual-----wpf-3-5).