# Красить ключевые слова во время написания текста

Tags: c#

При выводе из файла в richTextBox1 делаю так

```
private void ColorText()
    {
        string[] words = {"select", "from", "where" };

        for (int j = 0; j < words.Length; j++)
        {
            int i = 0;
            while (i <= richTextBox1.Text.Length - words[j].Length)
            {
                i = richTextBox1.Text.IndexOf(words[j], i);
                if (i < 0) break;
                richTextBox1.SelectionStart = i;
                richTextBox1.SelectionLength = words[j].Length;
                richTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Blue;
                i += words[j].Length;
            }
        }


    }
```

А как сделать чтобы при вводе с клавиатуры,   после написания очередного слова красить его в нужный цвет (после нажатия пробела).

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/421031/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-textblock-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-richtextbox

Comment: этот проектик смотрел, но он так и не доделан и не работает до конца правильно, а та часть что и работает тормозит еще хлеще чем у меня ,  и наворочено там мама моя дорогая , я прошу всего навсего раскраска последнего слова после нажатия пробел

Comment: Сейчас пробую так private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Space)
            {
                
            }
        }                                         а вот дальше что то тормажу,   по ходу надо  как то введенный текст запоминать в промежуточный текст ,   а по нажатию "пробел" сверять буфер с ключевыми словами и если это ключевое слово то красить

Comment: Возьмите готовый компонент: [Fast Colored TextBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting) или [Scintilla](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET).

Comment: Fast Colored TextBox   -   отличный  пример,  но мне он не идет,  мне надо всего навсего пару  строк кода которые красят слово введенное склавиатуры при нажатии клавиши пробел

Comment: а  пример  Scintilla   -   так там вообще библиотека,   хотя   тоже отличный пример ,   я их  посмотрел изучил большое спасибо,  но к сожелению не мой вариант