# Задача подсветки синтаксиса в текстовых полях Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, winforms

В веб-разработке, где у меня на момент написания этого вопроса было больше всего опыта, создание текстового редактора с подсветкой синтаксиса является крайне сложной задачей, что я понял, смотря исходные коды JSFidde и других популярных редакторов кода. Но как обстоит дело с решением подобных задача в Windows Form Application?

Допустим, нам надо сделать подсветку синтаксиса какого-нибудь редкого языка программирования и многострочном текстовом поле ввода. Есть какие-нибудь простые средства для этого в Windows Form Application, или как и веб-разработке, придётся танцевать с бубном?

Comment: Анализ синтаксических конструкций придется делать руками, а раскрашивать текст умеет RichTextBox. Но в целом, пожалуй задача действительно не тривиальная. Если нужно просто подсветить ключевые слова, то несколько проще, но нужен список этих слов.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423654/218063

Comment: Как насчет готовых контролов? Я когда то [делал подсветку](https://tym32167.blogspot.com/2011/12/avalonedit-avalondock.html) с помощью [avalonedit](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpDevelop/wiki/AvalonEdit)

Comment: Возьмите готовый компонент: [Fast Colored TextBox](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/161871/Fast-Colored-TextBox-for-syntax-highlighting) или [Scintilla](https://github.com/jacobslusser/ScintillaNET).