# Как иницилизировать Monaco Editor в CefSharp

Tags: c#, wpf, cefsharp

например путь к монако от самого ексешника такой: bin\Monaco
[image: папка монако]

Comment: Разве это не просто Web страничка, которую вы можете просто открыть как сайт? Если да, то в чем трудности вызываете метод открытия URL, но указываете там путь к файлу `index.html`.

Comment: И да, если вы делаете редактор кода или еще чего, то мне кажется оооочень странным решением брать прослойку в виде браузера, в которой вы будете открывать веб редактор, из которого потом будет выдергивать результат, ну и так далее. Это как открытие приложение, для запуска которого надо запустить виртуальную машину, на которой запустить еще приложение, внутри которого запускается еще приложение. Думаю понимаете, что это весьма странно, не? Если вам нужна подсветка, то [как пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423654/220553), другой функционал тоже сделать можно (жирный, курсив и др.).

Comment: мне нужно эти "IntelliSense" и сама подсветка, это красиво и выглядит хорошо, еще это как плюс к моему приложению будет

Comment: [Первая ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4791258/6808809) по запросу "wpf intellisense control" дает сразу и как сделать поддержку в своем проекте самому, и готовый прям редактор для WPF. И я уверен, что есть еще куча решений. Так что, повторю - очень странно брать **целый браузер**, открывать на нем **сайт**, и все это ради простого редактора...

Comment: браузер много ресурсов же не потребляет, уже готовый синтаксис есть, и дополнение
https://ctrlv.link/fKye
в обычном intellisense такого нету, приложение на скрине, достаточно быстрое, и потребляет не больше 100мб озу, никаких подвисаний или прочего никогда не было, использует это приложение CefSharp

Comment: Слушайте, я вам лишь советую, не настаиваю, не уговариваю, не заставляю. Я для вас вообще ноунейм, человек с интернета, слушать меня или нет - только ваш выбор. Мне лично вообще без разницы что вы там используете, как, зачем. Да хоть как я вон выше говорил виртуальную машину запускайте, на которой будет другая виртуальная и все ради того, чтобы работала программа) Просто для меня, если я допустим смогу сделать более оптимизированный проект, который будет быстрый, отзывчивый, без лишнего - это будет огромным плюсом, да и я больше с него получу (как в плане финансов, так и в плане знаний).

Comment: Вот пример из жизни - был заказ на бота для сайта, там использовался Steam в качестве авторизации, я тогда был вообще без знаний программирования, пошел к знакомому, который более-менее лучше разбирался в этом, ну мы с ним на тяп-ляп написали, используя для авторизации именно браузер (аналог CefSharp). Через пару лет (это было буквально год назад), заказчик хочет доработать проект, я открываю старый код и в ужасе не понимаю, что там происходит. В итоге я переписал его с нуля, без браузера, полностью эмулировал все этапы авторизации стим. А проект стал раз в 5 быстрее, RAM не 200мб а всего 25.

Comment: это очень хорошо, но у меня мало опыта, другие варианты кажутся сложнее, вроде кажется что легко, пару строк кода и страница есть, но когда я пытаюсь это сделать разными способами, ничего не выходит, либо ошибка либо просто пусто, в этом монако ведь все готово, а вот запустить не мог ни на webview2 ни на sefsharp, завтра попытаюсь еще что то придумать, может получиться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MonacoInitiliaze();
    
}

async void MonacoInitiliaze()
{
    await MonacoBr.EnsureCoreWebView2Async(null);
    MonacoBr.CoreWebView2.Navigate(Path.Combine("file:", Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "bin", "monaco", "index.html"));
}
```

это весь код который понадобился, спустя неделю решил проблему двумя строчками (сверху для webview2)

для cefsharp:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InitializeChromium();
    }


    public void InitializeChromium()
    {
        testbr.Address = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()  + "/bin/Monaco/index.html";
    }
```