# Редактор html в авалонии

Tags: c#, .net, avalonia

Мне нужно создать редактор html в авалоне без использования winform . Сейчас в нет 4.8 я использую mshtml.dll . Вопрос : есть ли в авалонии инструмент который даст мне возможность создать редактор html или можно ли подключить mshtml без потери linux и как это сделать если да , мои двухнедельные знания авалонии слишком скудны.

Comment: нет 4.8 это только Windows, вы что-то перепутали. А вообще HTML это просто текст, берете мультистрочкий TextBox и готово. Если нужен парсер HTML, то посмотрите на HtmlAgilityPack или AngleSharp.

Comment: Что в вашем понимании "редактор"? Блокнот с подсветкой синтаксиса - редактор? Вроде да.. Что тогда мешает взять простое текстовое поле и вывести туда весь HTML? Ну а подсветка, если она прям так нужна, то тоже решаемо сторонними решениями, либо [своим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/423654/220553). Зачем вы внедряете всякие .dll мне вообще не понятно... HTML это текст, не более. Ну а если нужно отображение этого HTML, то внедряйте браузер, самый новый на данный момент это WebView2.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ WebView2 это только Windows. Возможно CEF подойдёт, но я не уверен, что его реально завезти под авалонией.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , редактор для пользователя это программа с возможностями вроде word , пользователь не должен знать что такое тэги , он должен иметь возможность нажать кнопочку и описать на пальцах какую таблицу хочет или обвести текст и жмакнуть на кнопку создать пунктирную рамочку  или разместить текст по центру или много чего . А подсветка и прочее это скорее инструмент разработчика , пользователю это не надо .  WebView2 все это может только он никому ничего не скажет ди и у CTF я не увидел что-то вроде designMode  . Вот я и  спрашиваю есть ли у какой библиотеки режим designMode .

Comment: aepot , мне нужен редактор для пользователя , увидев внутренности html они  меня возненавидят .

Comment: Тогда вы сами себе противоречите. У вас в вопросе четко сказано `Мне нужно создать редактор html`, а HTML - это разметка, которой программисты описывают дизайн сайта. Сейчас вы пишете `пользователю это не надо`. Вы определитесь что хотите, а уж затем просите помощи. Мы не сидим у вас там за спиной, не видим вашего проекта, не знаем что вы делаете, мы сторонние люди, которые опираются только на то, что есть в вопросе. Хорошо, зачем вам тогда HTML, браузер, и прочее? Создайте кнопку  "Таблица", выведите на экран, пользователь отредактирует, потом по кнопке "сохранить" вы конвертируете в HTML.

Comment: Не очень понял как вы предлагаете создавать html ? у меня сейчас работает на базе mshtml такой в котором пользователь все делает видя результат сразу , может подвинуть контрол в любую сторону на любой поинт и расположить все так как ему нужно . Визуальный редактор , другой для пользователя не пойдет и да может я выразился не точно но и  rtf тоже разметка а ворд редактор текста вот с таким функционалом мне нужен редактор html , вернее мне нужна информация у какой библиотеки есть такая возможность и главное в авалонии.

Comment: Упоминание ставить не забывайте, ибо вы уведомления видите (ваш вопрос), а я нет, пока не будет упоминания меня в комментарии. `как вы предлагаете создавать html` - HTML это просто набор данных, немного измененный XML формат, который имеет строгую структуру, а значит мы его можем без труда генерировать на основе неких данных. Вот что вам мешает сделать условный класс `record User(string Name, int Age);` и на его основе сделать условный `<div><b>Вася</b> 24 года</div>`? Да вроде ничего. А что нужно пользователю для редактирования этого класса? Пара полей, да кнопка "сохранить", и вот редактор.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ да если бы , у меня больше 50 кнопок и 10% выпадающие , иначе ни ттн ни путевой лист не нарисовать как надо , да и отчетность вся на html а там поиск замена и много чего , с наскока не сделаешь , так что авалония на будущее , пока она слаба .

Comment: 50 кнопок - вы случаем данные с типом этих самых данных не путаете? Вот условно у вас есть "Имя: Вася" - что это? Наверно текстовое поле, в которое человек пишет "Вася", идем далее "Выезжает из Адрес1 до Адрес2" - а тут что? Наверно это два выпадающих списка с соответствующими данными для выбора, ну и так далее. Вот я вам назвал **два** элемента, которые человек может добавить на форуму и заполнить, вам остается продумать эти все элементы и реализовать, чтобы пользователь мог добавлять когда хочет и как. Посмотрите "Гугл формы", их редактор, вот такое я вам и предлагаю делать.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ , нет , просто у меня настоящий редактор , ну нужно иметь пользователям возможность сделать документ красивым . Например у кнопки горизонтального центрования должен выпадать список слева справа в центре , для вертикальной так же , если пользователь  хочет обвести текст рамочкой то каким бордюром каким цветом  так же шрифт так же размер шрифта . У таблицы своих параметров много кроме того удаление и добавление строки или ячейки ну еще положение контролов и их перемещение в четырех направлениях . Слияние ячеек горизонтально\вертикально и много чего  еще.